# Fragment Transactions not working through button

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

When I try to change from Fragment1 to Fragment2 it isn't working, but when I press the button it is still giving me the log info. I'm guessing its something with the transactions.Please someone help me to resolve this problem.

Logs/Error Messages:

```
 D/xd: please help idk why this isnt working //to prove that button click is working

 W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 2157350, only wrote 2157120
```

**mainmenu.java (activity)**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainmenu);
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.pager1);
    adapterViewPager = new FragmentCollectionAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1); //what fragment starts at mainmenu.


    //starting transaction for moving between fragments between buttons
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    //adding fragments to countainer or dashboard in our case
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container,new dashboard());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

**dashboard.java (Fragment1)**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreateView(inflater,container,savedInstanceState);
    dashboardView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard,container,false);

    //links the Button Variable to buttons on dashboard xml
    profilevar = (ImageButton) dashboardView.findViewById(R.id.profileButton);
    eventsvar = (ImageButton) dashboardView.findViewById(R.id.eventsButton);
    classesvar = (ImageButton) dashboardView.findViewById(R.id.classesButton);
    messagesvar = (ImageButton) dashboardView.findViewById(R.id.messagesButton);

    //when you click these buttons it will call the onClick method.
    profilevar.setOnClickListener(this);
    eventsvar.setOnClickListener(this);
    classesvar.setOnClickListener(this);
    messagesvar.setOnClickListener(this);

    return dashboardView;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    if(v == profilevar)
    {
        Log.d("xd","please help idk why this isnt working");
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new profile());
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
    if(v == eventsvar)
    {

    }
    if(v == messagesvar)
    {

    }
    if(v == classesvar)
    {

    }
}
```

**profile.java(Fragment2)**

```
public class profile extends Fragment{
public static profile newInstance()
{
    profile fragment = new profile();
    return fragment;
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreateView(inflater,container,savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile,container,false);
    return view;
}
}
```

fragment_profile.xml (Fragment 2)

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#5160dd"
tools:context=".profile" >

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Profile fragment"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:id="@+id/memetext"
    />

 </FrameLayout>
```

fragment_dashboard.xml (Fragment1)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/profileButton"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:contentDescription="profileButton"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.027"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/eventsButton"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:contentDescription="eventButton"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/messagesButton"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/classesButton"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/eventsButton"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/classesButton"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```

Comment: did `R.id.fragment_container` included in `R.layout.fragment_profile,container` ?

Comment: what do you mean by your comment?

Answer (score 0):

You try to switch like that

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
switch(v.getId()){

case R.id.profileButton:
{
    Log.d("xd","please help idk why this isnt working");
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new profile());
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
    break;
}
case R.id.eventsButton:
{
    break;
}
case R.id.classesButton:
{
    break;
}
case R.id.messagesButton:
{
    break;
 }
}

}
```

Comment: You want to switch on `v.getId()` not `v`

Comment: this doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

you may use Interface to change from one Fragment to another fragment. By Pressing the button in FIRST Fragment you can change to another Fragment..

[Fragment Transaction, Exchange Data Between Fragments](https://www.journaldev.com/14207/android-passing-data-between-fragments)

it will helps.. Thanks to ##journaldev...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `R.id.fragment_container` in `fragment_profile.xml`.

**Example**

```
 Log.d("xd","please help idk why this isnt working");
 FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new profile());
 transaction.addToBackStack(null);
 transaction.commit();
 break;
```

**fragment_profile.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
             android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                            android:id="@+id/recycleView">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: but i have the fragment_countainer in my dashboard? why should i do it twice?